# Get users language in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

I created a method, where the user can transfer credits(currency) to another user. If the operation is a success, sent an email to this user, who received credits, who sent. In email template, I use a trans() function. But when one of the users have selected English, and when second selected for example Russian language, email both the user receives in the language of the user who sent the credit.

For example, I use English language, user1 uses Estonian. When I transfer credits, letters languages will be only English.

Comment: There are probably lots of options for this, and the answer could get large. I created [a class](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid/blob/master/app/TG/TransMail.php) for my project. It's not the best feeling I have of it, but so far it serves well for the purpose. Hope it helps for ideas.

Comment: Is there an answer with trans() function? Is it probably to do the same with this function?

Comment: I actually use trans(), (you have to, anyway) but you need to first switch the language of your destination user... Thats why using a helper class first.